# Android DialogFragment BadParcelableException

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I tried to write a small example to reproduce my problem:

```
public class ActivityA extends FragmentActivity{

  private void showMyDialog(){
    SelectionDialog dialog = SelectionDialog.newInstance("title", new SelectionDialog.UploadFolderSelectionDialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void writeToParcel(Parcel arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public int describeContents() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return 0;
                }

                @Override
                public void folderSelected() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager());
  }
}

public class SelectionDialog extends DialogFragment {

  public static SelectionDialog newInstance(final String title, UploadFolderSelectionDialogListener listener) {
    SelectionDialog  dialog = new SelectionDialog ();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    args.putParcelable("listener", listener);
    dialog.setArguments(args);
    return dialog;
  }

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    if (getArguments().containsKey("title")) {
        alertBuilder.setTitle(getArguments().getInt("title"));
    }
    return alertBuilder.create();
  }

  public interface UploadFolderSelectionDialogListener extends Parcelable {
    void folderSelected();
  }
}
```

The problem:

1. Make sure the developer option "Don't keep activitites" is checked
2. Open the dialog
3. Press the HOME button
4. Open the App from the HOME launcher
5. Calling getArguments().get... causes an exception:

"android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class com....$1"

Following also didn't fix the issue: getArguments().setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());

Removing `args.putParcelable("listener", listener);` from the code avoids the crash.

Comment: can you post `com.sophos.smenc.LocalStorageProvider` class and it's inner classes

Comment: apparently the issue is that `LocalStorageProvider` is not properly following the Parcelable protocol. Your short example does not present the use of `LocalStorageProvider`, hence is not fit to reproduce your issue.

Comment: (Also, did you consider reading the `Parcelable` interface documentation?)

Comment: LocalStorageProvider is not the problem, I will post a mini project on Github so you can see

Comment: and all works normally, only when Don't keep activities is activated it doesn't work.

Comment: Good, I created a small project and wasn't able to reproduce it. I replaced now im ny original project the original dialog by the small one I constructed and with it the problem is not reproducible, so the problem should be with my original dialog and I'm not seeing what it could be.

Comment: Ok, I found the difference now with my original dialog, I updated my question. Using args.putParcelable makes the difference, I don't even need to call getParcelable, the app will crash on any getArguemnts().get...